# Problema con tablas relacionadas MYSQL

Tags: mysql

Tengo la tabla productos

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tabla_productos` (
  `id_producto` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `nombre` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `descripcion` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  `precio` DOUBLE NOT NULL,
  `marca` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  `categoria` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `stock` INT(6) NOT NULL,
  `id_imagen` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_producto`, `id_imagen`, `categoria`),
  UNIQUE INDEX `id_productos_UNIQUE` (`id_producto` ASC),
  INDEX `categoria_idx` (`categoria` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `categoria`
    FOREIGN KEY (`categoria`)
    REFERENCES `tabla_categorias` (`id_categoria`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;

ALTER TABLE `tabla_productos` ADD  `camara_prinicpal` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL;
ALTER TABLE `tabla_productos`  ADD `memoria_ram` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL;
ALTER TABLE `tabla_productos` ADD  `memoria_rom` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL;
ALTER TABLE `tabla_productos` ADD  `display`  VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL;
ALTER TABLE `tabla_productos`  ADD `procesador` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL;
ALTER TABLE `tabla_productos` ADD  `sistema_operativo`  VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL;
ALTER TABLE `tabla_productos` ADD `estado` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL;
```

A su vez, cada producto tiene mas de una imagen que la represente

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tabla_imagenes` (
  `id_imagen` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `url_imagen` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  `id_producto_imagen` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  CONSTRAINT `id_producto_imagen`
    FOREIGN KEY (`id_producto_imagen`)
    REFERENCES `tabla_productos` (`id_producto`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

**La tabla de productos usa `id_imagen` INT(11) NOT NULL** para unrise con la tabla de imagenes mediante **`id_producto_imagen` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT.**

***El problema es el siguiente***

Quiero obtener los productos, ***PERO QUE SOLAMENTE ME MUESTRE UNA IMAGEN SOLA, NO LAS 2 O 3 QUE PUEDAN ESTAR RELACIONADAS***

Intente con subconsultas, la siguiente

```
SELECT producto.id_producto, producto.nombre, producto.id_imagen, 
       imagen.id_producto_imagen, imagen.url_imagen 

       FROM tabla_productos producto JOIN tabla_imagenes imagen
       ON producto.id_imagen = (SELECT imagen.id_producto_imagen FROM tabla_imagenes LIMIT 1);
```

No funciona, por que me trae todos los productos, con todas sus imagenes.

Este es el codigo que me muestra el PHP

```
Array
(
    [id_producto] => 1
    [0] => 1
    [nombre] => Iphone 6
    [1] => Iphone 6
    [id_imagen] => 1
    [2] => 1
    [id_producto_imagen] => 1
    [3] => 1
    [url_imagen] => P001.jpg
    [4] => P001.jpg
)

Array
(
    [id_producto] => 1
    [0] => 1
    [nombre] => Iphone 6
    [1] => Iphone 6
    [id_imagen] => 1
    [2] => 1
    [id_producto_imagen] => 1
    [3] => 1
    [url_imagen] => P001_1.jpg
    [4] => P001_1.jpg
)

Array
(
    [id_producto] => 1
    [0] => 1
    [nombre] => Iphone 6
    [1] => Iphone 6
    [id_imagen] => 1
    [2] => 1
    [id_producto_imagen] => 1
    [3] => 1
    [url_imagen] => P001_2.jpg
    [4] => P001_2.jpg
)
```

Me trae 3 veces el mismo producto

Comment: Tienes que hacer un inner join de la tabla productos con la tabla imagenes y de hay hacer el limit 1

Comment: Ya intente eso, pero no es lo que estoy buscando. Por que me trae el producto con ID 1 y su imagen. Pero solamente un producto solo, y yo quiero todos lo de mi tabla

Comment: Hola, ¿quieres que la consulta muestre los productos solo con una imagen cualquiera? creo que se puede hacer de forma simple

Comment: Hola. Como seria esa opcion ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una solución simple a tu problema puede ser usar `group by` y `any_value()` de la siguiente forma:

```
SELECT producto.id_producto, producto.nombre, producto.id_imagen, 
       any_value(imagen.id_producto_imagen) as id_producto_imagen, any_value(imagen.url_imagen) as url_imagen

       FROM tabla_productos producto inner JOIN tabla_imagenes imagen
       ON producto.id_imagen = imagen.id_producto_imagen
group by producto.id_producto
```

Primero unes los datos con `inner join`, eso te mostrará los datos relacionados pero repetidos, para reducirlos puedes usar `group by` agrupandolos por `ìd`, luego usas `any_value()` que en caso de cadenas elegirá y mostrará una de todas las posibles.

Espero te sea de ayuda, saludos.

Comment: si lo quieres agrupados por producto @Eric este ejemplo te vale solo necesitas poner como te indica el compañero group by producto

Comment: Gracias a ambos, es justamente lo que estaba buscando.

Comment: @Eric, de nada, que tengas buen día.